# How to import a mathematica notebook into another mathematica notebook?

Tags: import

I have a number of notebooks -295 precisely- in a folder. Each notebook contains one or more large matrices. What is the proper way of importing each one of these notebooks in a new notebook for manipulations?

I tried

```
Import["Name of desired notebook", 
"path of the notebook"]
```

And it does not work. I am getting the following error message:

"Import: File not found during import"

For the path of the notebook I just copy the exact result after I do command+i -I am working on a mac.

Can someone explain to me what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you change the .nb files to something else, like package files (.wl/.m) or .mx files? Because notebook files are really not designed to be imported into other files... If you need to use .nb files, look at the documentation of [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html), your syntax is currently wrong. You can also look at the documentation of the [NB](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/NB.html) file format - you could mark the cells with the matrices as initialization cells and import the `"Initialization"` import element.

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestions.

Comment: Since each notebook contains a matrix, why not evaluate all the notebooks, i.e., use NotebookEvaluate (instead of importing). That way the current session will have the data associated with all the notebooks.

Comment: Try `NotebookEvaluate[<file_name>, InsertResults -> False]`.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, fyi `NotebookEvaluate` unlike `Import` doesn't support remote files - eg shared on cloud.

Comment: @alancalvitti Thanks for pointing out that limitation. When is your Functional Dataflow book going to be published?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, thanks for asking - I'd like to have it out this summer. While the material is essentially completed, code review and indexing is taking the bulk of the time.

Comment: You can also do ```NotebookImport["nameofnotebook.nb",_ -> "Expression"];```. At least, this is what I use. It is probably equivalent to the ```NotebookEvaluate``` solutions.